# What does "wc --files0-from=F" mean in linux command

Tags: linux, man

I read the manual of wc command but could not understand the explanation of this parameter. Please help.

The official explanation is below:

```
--files0-from=F
read input from the files specified by NUL-terminated names in file F; If
F is - then read names from standard input
```

Answer (score 6):

`read input from the files specified ... in file F`

Instead of supplying the filenames to `wc` on the command line, read them from file F.

`NUL-terminated names`

The file names in file F must be separated by the NUL character (byte value 0) instead of newlines, tabs or spaces. This is to correctly handle filenames that contain whitespace.

`If F is - then read names from standard input`

Rather than specifying a real file F, the filenames can be read from standard input which can be fed from a pipe. In this instance, the filenames are still expected to be NUL-terminated. A typical example of this would be `find ... -printf0 | wc ... --files0-from=-`

Comment: How can you write NUL-terminated file names?

Comment: @ivanacorovic, usually the NUL-terminated filenames are the output of another program. For example, the `find` utility normally returns results separated by newlines but you can use the `-printf0` option to have it return results separated by NUL. This is useful when passing filenames with spaces to another program (such as `wc` in the original question) which treats white space a separators by default.